# SQL Sort Month Ascending and Months Descending?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible if I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Fun` (
  `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

to perform an SQL query where the results are sorted like this:

```
2013-03-01
2013-03-03
2013-03-04
2013-02-11
2013-02-28
2013-01-21
2012-12-10
2012-12-25
2010-07-08
```

Note that, in the list above, the months and years are sorted in descending order, but the days within each month are sorted in ascending order?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take advantage of `YEAR`, `MONTH` function.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Fun
ORDER   BY YEAR(date) DESC, MONTH(date) DESC,
        DATE ASC
```